# What are differences between audit action groups of AUDIT SPECIFICATION and audit event class of sql tracer in Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, audit, audit-trail

I want to know differences between audit action groups of AUDIT SPECIFICATION and audit event class of SQL Tracer in Microsoft SQL Server.

I intend to implement a logging program by setting audit event class through sp_trace_setevent procedure.

Using audit event class of SQL Tracer, how much performance is decreased relative to using audit action groups of AUDIT SPECIFICATION?

I also wish to know differences of action mechanism between them.

Answer (score 2):

According to MSDN, both Server-level and Datavase-level audit action groups are actions similar to SQL Server security audit event classes. You can find the list of equivalent action groups and event classes here: [SQL Server Audit Action Groups and Actions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280663.aspx)

The overhead of the SQL Server Audit feature is lighter than of auditing using SQL traces, but the overall impact depends on how busy the database is and how many events you want to audit